# Code that checks if an excel file is open works on one computer (user), but will it work with more computers (users)?

Tags: vba, excel

The following code checks if file is open, if not, it opens it and copies something into it. It works fine on my computer. Will it work, when the file is shared and another user opens the file? Will my code detect it?

```
Sub copy_to_boss()
    On Error Resume Next                                                   
    team = "boss.xlsm"                                                 
    Set fileBoss = Workbooks(team)
    fileIsOpen = Not fileBoss Is Nothing

    If fileIsOpen = True Then
        MsgBox "The following file is open " & team & " - close it."
    Else
        MsgBox "I will open the following file " & team
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=team
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "10"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No, It will not work because each person has their own `Workbooks` collection, and you cannot look at other peoples' `Workbook` collections. However, there are other ways to see if a file is currently in use.

Comment: why are you asking? just run a test

Comment: braX: thank you, I thought so :-( What other solution would you recommend? I am a beginner. I found one based on checking if a file is read-only, but this will not work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test_LockFile()
Dim sFile     As String
Dim sLockFile As String
Dim objFSO    As Object
'Trick: Each Excel file in use has a temporary file companion with prefix "~$"
'       (e.g. "test.xlsm" ... "$~test.xlsm")
'Define sLockFile
 sFile = ThisWorkbook.Name
 sLockFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\~$" & sFile

'FileSystemObject, late Binding ohne Nutzung von IntelliSense und autom. Konstanten
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Show message if file is locked
 If objFSO.FileExists(sLockFile) Then
   MsgBox "The file " & sLockFile & " is locked by some user.", vbInformation, sFile & " is locked"
 Else
   MsgBox "The file is available", vbInformation, sFile
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: T.M.: I like your solution, just an additional question: why do I need this line:  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ? I tried to google it, but it didn't help much.

Comment: @fukacka, `CreateObject` sets objFSO to memory after being declared in the first code lines.
For this `Dim` declaration you can use
a) early binding allowing e.g. Intellisense, but you have to enable reference to MS Scripting Runtime lib in your VBE, b) late binding as shown below without Intellisense - usually used to be platform independant. In case a) you'll have to declare your object variable e.g.
`Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject` instead of the neutral `Dim objFSO As Object` in case b). CreateObject allows Excel to use the same functionalities as in case a).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to check if the file is in use:

```
Public Function IsFileLocked(PathName As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Dim i As Integer

  If Len(Dir$(PathName)) Then
    i = FreeFile()
    Open PathName For Random Access Read Write Lock Read Write As #i
    Lock i 'Redundant but let's be 100% sure
    Unlock i
    Close i
  Else
    Err.Raise 53
  End If

ExitProc:
  On Error GoTo 0
  Exit Function

ErrHandler:
  Select Case Err.Number
    Case 70 'Unable to acquire exclusive lock
      IsFileOpen = True
    Case Else
      MsgBox "Error " &amp; Err.Number &amp; " (" &amp; Err.Description &amp; ")"
    End Select
  Resume ExitProc
  Resume
End Function
```